# Ember Controllers and Routes

Tags: ember.js

I'm sure there is a much easier way to accomplish my current task but this is the only way I know how to do so far since I am just starting out with Ember.

So I have a RESTful api which tells ember which user is currently logged in (their name only) so that it can be displayed on the page as `Signed in As {{currentUser}}`. The only way I have been able to make it work is by extending the application route as such:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    var deferredData = Ember.Deferred.create();          
    var list = [];
    $.getJSON( '/user/profile/', function(data) {
      list.push({
        currentUser: data[0].name
      })
      deferredData.resolve(list);
    });
    return deferredData;
  }
});
```

and then on my page doing:

```
<p class="navbar-text navbar-right">
    <p class="navbar-text navbar-right">Signed in as {{#link-to 'account' class="navbar-link" id="current-user"}}{{#each}}{{currentUser}}{{/each}}{{/link-to}}</p>
</p>
```

It works but I feel as if this is not the appropriate way of accomplishing my task. I tried using `App.ApplicationController` with the following:

```
App.ApplicationControler = Ember.Controller.extend({
  currentUser: function() {
    $.getJSON( '/user/profile/', function(data) {
      return data[0].name
    });
  }.property()
});
```

That didn't work for me either. Any ideas what I should do/what I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

After some more reading around this is now what I have and I *think* it's the closest I've come to getting it right

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  currentUser: function() {
    return $.getJSON('/user/profile/').then( function(response) {
      console.log(response[0].name);
      return response[0].name;
    });
  }.property()
});

App.applicationController = App.ApplicationController.create();
```

Would using data stores and `RESTadapters` be a better choice for me at this point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my issue. I was trying to set the response to just one value but that wouldn't work because that value wouldn't be stringified. To fix this problem I did the following:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return $.getJSON('/user/profile/').then( function(data) {
      return { 
        currentUser: data[0] 
      };
    });
  }
});
```

and in my view I did the following:

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="navigation">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        {{#link-to 'index' class="navbar-brand"}}Budgeter{{/link-to}}
        <p class="navbar-text navbar-right">
          Signed in as {{#link-to 'account' class="navbar-link" id="current-user"}}{{currentUser.name}}{{/link-to}}
        </p>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li>{{#link-to 'index'}}<i class="fa fa-home sp-aft"></i>Home{{/link-to}}</li>
          <li>{{#link-to 'account'}}<i class="fa fa-user sp-aft"></i>Account{{/link-to}}</li>
          <li><a href="/logout"><i class="fa fa-sign-out sp-aft"></i>Sign Out</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </script>
```

Works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

You should use whichever data adapter you're using for other data. Plain $.ajax is fine, if that's what you're using.

The first attempt with `route.model` hook and rendering navbar into the `application` template is the correct way to do this. I'm not sure, however, why are you creating an array when you only seem to need one. Try this:

```js
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return $.getJSON('/user/profile/')
            .then(function (data) {
                return {
                    currentUser: data[0].name
                };
            });
    }
});
```

application.hbs:

```html
<p class="navbar-text navbar-right">
    <p class="navbar-text navbar-right">
        Signed in as {{#link-to 'account' class="navbar-link" id="current-user"}}{{currentUser}}{{/link-to}}
    </p>
</p>
```

Ah, yes. And you should define your `ApplicationController` as:

```js
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({});
```

... so you would have direct access to your model object.

Comment: Ok i tried this out but it renders out on my page as `[object Object]`

Comment: [Here's a working example with Ember.RSVP simulating ajax](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zasowuho/1/edit?html,js,output). Check what you're getting from `data[0].name`.